# Define a DispatcherServlet in annotation base config?

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot

I upgrade my xml base application to the spring boot
My problem is `org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet` in the web.xml

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher1</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
        <async-supported>true</async-supported>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher1</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

How i config above xml config in annotation config?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the default Spring Boot dispatcher servlet mapping you need to create a custom servlet bean and register it with the desired path. The following example shows how to do it in Java configuration.

```
@Bean
public DispatcherServlet dispatcherServlet() {
    return new DispatcherServlet();
}

@Bean
public ServletRegistrationBean servletRegistrationBean(DispatcherServlet dispatcherServlet) {
    ServletRegistrationBean registration = new ServletRegistrationBean(dispatcherServlet, "/rest/*");
    registration.setName(DispatcherServletAutoConfiguration.DEFAULT_DISPATCHER_SERVLET_REGISTRATION_BEAN_NAME);
    return registration;
}
```

You can read more details in [this article](http://www.leveluplunch.com/java/tutorials/011-add-servlet-mapping-to-dispatcherservlet-spring-boot/).